# Can GTK2 and GTK3 coexist?

Tags: 14.04, geany, virtual-terminal

Geany uses the Virtual terminal emulator widget for GTK+ 2.0 (`libvte9`), in particular the `libvte.so` library.

Since Ubuntu 14.04 LTS uses the Terminal emulator widget for GTK+ 3.0 (`libvte-2.90-9`), I am wondering if I can install `libvte9` alongside `libvte-2.90-9`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, GTK2 and GTK3 can co-exist. Even on 16.04, I can use older gtk-2 apps.

Geany even works on 16.04 Xenial.